# Polygon cordinates to array

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have an array of Polygons where each object looks like this

```
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((-98.03706782884247, 44.72279408402323), (-98.03706782884247, 44.71524098343729), (-98.02951472825653, 44.71524098343729), (-98.02951472825653, 44.72279408402323), (-98.03706782884247, 44.72279408402323)),)}
```

I need to convert the coordinates to an array and it should look like

```
[[[-98.03706782884247, 44.72279408402323],[-98.03706782884247, 44.71524098343729], [-98.02951472825653, 44.71524098343729], [-98.02951472825653, 44.72279408402323], [-98.03706782884247, 44.72279408402323]]]
```

Is there a pre-defined method which is available for polygons?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged `shapely`, have a look at [`shapely.geometry.asShape()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.asShape) to interpret a GeoJSON-like mapping as a shapely object

```py
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import asShape

d = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((-98.03706782884247, 44.72279408402323), (-98.03706782884247, 44.71524098343729), (-98.02951472825653, 44.71524098343729), (-98.02951472825653, 44.72279408402323), (-98.03706782884247, 44.72279408402323)),)}

geom = asShape(d)

print(geom)

# LinearRings can be viewed as numpy arrays
print(np.asarray(geom.exterior))
for interior in geom.interiors:
    print(np.asarray(interior))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the coordinates key values to a list.

```
what_your_looking_for = list(your_json_object['coordinates'])
```